# Flipping Platonic solids

Tags: mathematics, geometry

A cube is flipping on a table along its edges without sliding.

If the cube flips two steps forward, two steps to the left, two steps backward, two steps to the right, then the cube is back to its original position and orientation, i.e. every face is back to its original position.

It turns out that eight is the minimum number of steps to achieve this, assuming that no two consecutive steps cancel the effects of each other, such as flipping to the left and then immediately to the right.

Thus we say that the "flipping number" of the cube is eight.

What are the flipping numbers of the other four Platonic solids?

Comment: Do you know each of the numbers? I imagine the dodecahedron flipping number would be difficult to find/prove.

Comment: Given there are no constraints about "visiting" all faces of each Platonic solid, couldn't you just go forward once and then backwards once? I don't see anything in the rules that prevents it..

Comment: @Auribouros It explicitly says that the flipping number is "minimum ... assuming that no two consecutive steps cancel the effects of each other".

Comment: Completely omitted that in my head (and eyes apparently), thanks!

Comment: Does anyone know of a website where we can flip any of these solids? I used to have many of them in rubiks type puzzles but gave them all away, and these shapes are not easy to find around the house, and I have yet to find a good platonic solids manipulator online. This one doesn't work well for this "flipping" problem: https://polyhedra.tessera.li/tetrahedron/list

Answer (score 6):

I think I worked these out right (by computer search). Solutions given by describing moves according to absolute direction (degrees).

Tetrahedron

> 6 moves: 0, 300, 240, 180, 120, 60
>
>  This is just fixing one vertex and rotating around it.

Octahedron

> 12 moves: 0, 300, 240, 180, 120, 60, 0, 300, 240, 180, 120, 60
>
>  This is just fixing one vertex and rotating around it, but it has to be done twice to restore the orientation.

Icosahedron

> 18 moves: 0, 300, 240, 180, 120, 60, 0, 60, 120, 180, 120, 60, 0, 300, 240, 180, 240, 300

Dodecahedron

> 10 moves: 0, 252, 144, 36, 72, 180, 72, 324, 216, 252